# Node: Check if URL is safe to request

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, url

I am collecting URLs from visitors of my site that I then (on-demand) request from my backend. However, I have gotten stuck on the validation of the URL.

A URL is safe to request when:

- It is a valid URL
- It is unambiguous (in RFC 1918 terms, it is public)

What I have found so far:

- The URL interface (validates URLs)
- The ipaddr.js library (validates IPs)
- The is-valid-domain library (Looks to be broken, since it returns true for 256.256.256.256)

However, none of these seems to do what I need it to - not even a combination of them does.

Is there anything I have overlooked?

Comment: I found a interesting Post here, hope it helps you!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931191/10648655

Comment: @Antax Unfortunately, that doesn't check whether the URL is public or not. Also, it says that 'http://256.256.256.256' is a valid url.

Comment: check that link: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-identify-when-an-IP-address-is-private-or-public

Comment: @N00b I know how to identify a private IP address by hand (I even referenced RFC 1918), but the link does not contain any code.

Comment: And you get your clients ip?

Comment: @N00b I get a URL (https://123.123.123.123/api/x) and I need to check whether is is OK to give it an HTTP request.

Comment: Sorry cannot really help with nodejs, but if you want use also php, there is those functions to check ip and url. Change language for that if there is no reason to make code with nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I used:

- The URL interface for URL validation
- The [hostname-is-private NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostname-is-private)

First, I validate the input with `new URL(input)`, and then I use `require('hostname-is-private').isPrivate` (this is an async function) on that URL.hostname. This also works on IP addresses (even if the name does not suggest that).

The code looks something like this:

```
let isPrivate = require('hostname-is-private').isPrivate;

function validateURL(urlstr, cb) {
  try {
    let url = new URL(urlstr);
    isPrivate(url.hostname, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {cb(false)}
      cb(!res);
    })
  } catch (e) {
    return cb(false);
  }
}
```